# Fixed Navigation hiding under google maps and moving when clicked after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have placed google maps inside the last div at the bottom of the page. When I scroll down to this div google maps overlays on top of the navigation bar even though it does not do this with any other element. How do I prevent Google maps from overlaying the navigation bar when scrolling to the bottom of the pag?

Also the navigation bar is fixed, however i'm experiencing an issue where if you click on the drop down menu after having scrolled down the page it will move back to the top of the page, leaving the user where they scrolled to without the navigation bar available so in order to access the navigation bar you having to scroll all the way back to the top of the page

```css
 body {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0px;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
   color: #444;
   font: .9em Arial, sans-serif;
 }

 .topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: white;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .topnav a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #185b9b;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #efefef;
   color: #2672b2;
 }

 .active {
   background-color: white;
   color: white;
 }

 .topnav .icon {
   display: none;
 }

 .menu-icons {
   display: flex;
   height: 48px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
     display: none;
   }
   .topnav a.icon {
     float: right;
     display: block;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav.responsive {
     position: relative;
   }
   .topnav.responsive a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }

 .main {
   padding: 16px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .logo {
   max-height: 15px;
   max-width: 160px;
 }

 .header {
   height: 200px;
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 }

 .wrapper {
   box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   background-color: white;
 }

 #one {
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   min-height: 130px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 #one img {
   max-height: 25px;
   max-width: 160px;
 }

 #map {
   float: left;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   min-height: 750px;
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
 }

 

 #two {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10px;
   min-height: 130px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 910px) {
   #one {
     float: none;
     margin-right: 10;
     width: auto;
     border: 0;
   }
  #map {
     float: none;
     margin-right: 10;
     width: auto;
     border: 0;
   }
 }

.container {
   max-width: 800px;
   height: 600px;
   margin: 40px auto;
   padding: 0px 40px 40px 40px;
 }

 h1 {
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-size: 45px;
   margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
   color: #185b9b;
 }

 .input,
 .msg .area {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   border: 2px solid #e9eaea;
   font-size: 14px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   outline: none;
   transform: all 0.5s ease;
 }

 .login .input {
   width: 48%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 4%;
 }

 .login .input:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
 }

 .enter .btn2 {
   width: 48%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 4%;
 }

 .enter .btn2:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
 }
 .msg .area {
   height: 200px;
 }

 .btn {
   
   background: #185b9b;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

.btn2 {
  
   background: #185b9b;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .input:focus,
 .msg .area:focus {
   border: 2px solid #486255;
 }

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-family: 'roboto';
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <div>
        <a href="#home" class="active"><img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" /></a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#download">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-icons">
        <a href="tel:800-922-0204" class="icon">
<i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="header">
        <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere
          ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..
        </p>

        <p>
          Fixed bar The Worl'd Finest?
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="wrapper">
       <div id="map" class="float"></div>
        <div id="two">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Let's work together.</h1>

            <div class="login">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="subject">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="msg">
              <textarea class="area" placeholder="Leave a Message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="btn">Send Message</div>

            <div class="enter">
              <div class="btn2">Call 1-800-922-0204</div>
              <div class="btn2"> Download PDF</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <footer>
        <p>Copyright © 2019 Logo Name, LLC. All Rights Reserved</p>
        <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">someone@example.com</a>.</p>
      </footer>

    </div>



    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }
function initMap() {
    var location = {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      Zoom: 4,
      center: location
    });
  }

</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBYzXj5wF4L6mChyyc5xwfb2QT1QEZ9VN8&callback=initMap">


</script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have update css on `.topnav` and `#map` . Now map will not overlap on nav bar.

```css
body {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0px;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
   color: #444;
   font: .9em Arial, sans-serif;
 }

 .topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: white;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   z-index: 2;
 }

 .topnav a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #185b9b;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #efefef;
   color: #2672b2;
 }

 .active {
   background-color: white;
   color: white;
 }

 .topnav .icon {
   display: none;
 }

 .menu-icons {
   display: flex;
   height: 48px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
     display: none;
   }
   .topnav a.icon {
     float: right;
     display: block;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav.responsive {
     position: relative;
   }
   .topnav.responsive a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }

 .main {
   padding: 16px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .logo {
   max-height: 15px;
   max-width: 160px;
 }

 .header {
   height: 200px;
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 }

 .wrapper {
   box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   background-color: white;
 }

 #one {
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   min-height: 130px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 #one img {
   max-height: 25px;
   max-width: 160px;
 }

 #map {
   float: left;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   min-height: 750px;
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
 }

 

 #two {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10px;
   min-height: 130px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 910px) {
   #one {
     float: none;
     margin-right: 10;
     width: auto;
     border: 0;
   }
  #map {
     float: none;
     margin-right: 10;
     width: auto;
     border: 0;
   }
 }

.container {
   max-width: 800px;
   height: 600px;
   margin: 40px auto;
   padding: 0px 40px 40px 40px;
 }

 h1 {
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-size: 45px;
   margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
   color: #185b9b;
 }

 .input,
 .msg .area {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   border: 2px solid #e9eaea;
   font-size: 14px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   outline: none;
   transform: all 0.5s ease;
 }

 .login .input {
   width: 48%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 4%;
 }

 .login .input:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
 }

 .enter .btn2 {
   width: 48%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 4%;
 }

 .enter .btn2:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
 }
 .msg .area {
   height: 200px;
 }

 .btn {
   
   background: #185b9b;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

.btn2 {
  
   background: #185b9b;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .input:focus,
 .msg .area:focus {
   border: 2px solid #486255;
 }

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-family: 'roboto';
 }
```

```html
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <div>
        <a href="#home" class="active"><img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" /></a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#download">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-icons">
        <a href="tel:800-922-0204" class="icon">
<i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="header">
        <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere
          ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..
        </p>

        <p>
          Fixed bar The Worl'd Finest?
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="wrapper">
       <div id="map" class="float"></div>
        <div id="two">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Let's work together.</h1>

            <div class="login">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="subject">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="msg">
              <textarea class="area" placeholder="Leave a Message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="btn">Send Message</div>

            <div class="enter">
              <div class="btn2">Call 1-800-922-0204</div>
              <div class="btn2"> Download PDF</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <footer>
        <p>Copyright © 2019 Logo Name, LLC. All Rights Reserved</p>
        <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">someone@example.com</a>.</p>
      </footer>

    </div>



    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }

      function initMap() {
        var location = {
          lat: -25.363,
          lng: 131.044
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          Zoom: 4,
          center: location
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBYzXj5wF4L6mChyyc5xwfb2QT1QEZ9VN8&callback=initMap">


    </script>
```

Comment: This solved the google maps issue thank you! Do you know what is causing the fixed position of the navigation bar to shift when clicked after having already scrolled down the page?

Comment: Not understand you question?

Comment: if you scroll down the page in mobile view and click the hamburger menu the navigation bar jumps to the top of the page even though its position is supposed to be fixed